# How to modify HTML string effectively in PowerShell?

Tags: html, powershell

I have this piece of PowerShell code.

```
$html = @"
<table>
    <colgroup><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/></colgroup>
    <tr><td>447.1</td><td>365.5</td><td>81.6</td><td>81.8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>953.9</td><td>412.7</td><td>541.2</td><td>43.3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>953.3</td><td>145.2</td><td>808.1</td><td>15.2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1,863.0</td><td>1,466.4</td><td>396.6</td><td>78.7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1,863.0</td><td>863.9</td><td>999.1</td><td>46.4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>931.5</td><td>183.1</td><td>748.4</td><td>19.7</td></tr>
</table>
"@
```

How can I add a class "cls1" to column 1, 3 and 4? Is there a way for me to do it like in JavaScript? I don't want to use regex to parse it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is valid XHTML, so you can use a [.NET XML parser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument):

```sh
# Create an instance of XmlDocument (alias [xml])
$xml = [xml]::new(); $xml.PreserveWhitespace = $true

# Parse the XHTML string
$xml.LoadXml( $html )

foreach( $row in $xml.table.tr ) {
    $row.ChildNodes | Where-Object Name -eq 'td' | 
        Select-Object -Index 0,2,3 | 
        ForEach-Object { $_.SetAttribute('class','cls1') }
}

$xml.OuterXml
```

**Output:**

```text
<table>
    <colgroup><col /><col /><col /><col /><col /><col /></colgroup>
    <tr><td class="cls1">447.1</td><td>365.5</td><td class="cls1">81.6</td><td class="cls1">81.8</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="cls1">953.9</td><td>412.7</td><td class="cls1">541.2</td><td class="cls1">43.3</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="cls1">953.3</td><td>145.2</td><td class="cls1">808.1</td><td class="cls1">15.2</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="cls1">1,863.0</td><td>1,466.4</td><td class="cls1">396.6</td><td class="cls1">78.7</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="cls1">1,863.0</td><td>863.9</td><td class="cls1">999.1</td><td class="cls1">46.4</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="cls1">931.5</td><td>183.1</td><td class="cls1">748.4</td><td class="cls1">19.7</td></tr>
</table>
```

**Remarks:**

- `$xml.table.tr` … uses [member access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.3) to dive into the XML tree, creating an array of `<tr>` elements
- For accessing `<td>` elements we can't use `.td` member access, because PowerShell converts elements that contain only text into simple strings. We need an `XmlElement` though to be able to set attributes via its `SetAttribute` method. Therefore we have to use the `.ChildNodes` property.
- `Where-Object` filters childnodes by name, for added robustness.
- `Select-Object -Index` gives us the `<td>` elements at the specified column indices.
- `ForEach-Object` processes each of the selected `<td>` elements. Within the script block `{…}` the `$_` variable stands for the current element and allows us to call the .NET `.SetAttribute` method.